# Techniques for locating CDN origin hosts

Tags: network

Are there any known techniques for discovering origin hosts behind CDNs? I've had problems in the past where code was deployed that exposed origins to the public, and were publicly available.

Comment: A lot of this depends on how you are using the CDN. Without more information, people can't answer this question. Alternatively, it sounds like you just need to wget/spider the CDN hosted sites and grep for known (internal IP's) that may have leaked out or better yet have this run as a pre-deployment check before pushing files to your CDN.

Comment: Did you even do any research by your own? Like simply studying the top results for the search [exposing host behind CDN](https://www.google.com/search?q=exposing+host+behind+CDN)?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yes I did, but it seems my queries were not as honed as yours.